# How to quit a file window using applescript?

Tags: macos, applescript, finder

I would like to quit a file window using applescript.

Example: Imagine foo.rtf is opened, I want to quit the app using the following script

```
tell application "Finder" to quit "/Users/xyz/Desktop/foo.rtf"
```

Result:
Instead of quitting the file it quits Finder but not the file

Answer (score 0):

1. A window does not respond to `quit`, a window responds to `close`.
2. The Finder is not the target app of an RTF file, you have to tell the target app to close the window. However this works only if the target app has an AppleScript dictionary containing a `window` element. If not you can close the window with System Events and GUI scripting.

Comment: thank you it sounds like it is impossible to manage files using applescript because we can't be sure what is the target app set by the user. For instance RTF file can open in default text editor or user might set their default app to that file type.